# Read/get remote webrtc stream from OBS.ninja with Python aiortc

Tags: python, obs, aiortc

I'm trying to read/get a remote stream which is provided via [OBS.ninja](https://obs.ninja), process it (do some kind of object detection) and then send the new stream to another server. I'm wondering if [aiortc](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc) is the correct library/tooling for it or if I should concentrate on another framework. On the one hand I feel like it should be a good fit as OBS.ninja uses WebRTC, but from the examples in the aiortc github section it looks more like it is used for sending streams, but not receiving remote (browser)streams.